# As a [PHP]websocket-server how do i set a status code on a closing frame?

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

a closing control frame looks like

```
type:"close"
[payload:""]
```

so we dont have to send a status code and/or (string)reason.
But if we want to - how?

I read from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.1
that the code and reason belongs into the "application data"
which is append to the payload.
So in this case the payload is the application data. So far so good.

Then it says:

> If there is a body, the first two bytes of
> the body MUST be a 2-byte unsigned integer (in network byte order)
> representing a status code with value /code/ defined in Section 7.4.
> Following the 2-byte integer, the body MAY contain UTF-8-encoded data
> with value /reason/, the interpretation of which is not defined by
> this specification.
> Blockquote

first two bytes - 2-byte unsigned integer **-- OK, for example 1001**

body MAY contain UTF-8-encoded data with value /reason/ **-- OK**

But which format?

```
 type: close
 payload: 1001shutdown
```

oO?

I doubt that there is no format. Anybody know how?

= = = = = = = = = =

EDIT

thanks to Ghedipunk!
here some code in case somebody wants to use it:

```
public function encodeClosePayload($code, $reason='')
{
    $code = $this->closeCodeDecToBytes($code);
    return $code . $reason;
}
public function decodeClosePayload($payload)
{
    $code = $this->closeCodeBytesToDec(substr($payload, 0, 2));
    $reason = (strlen($payload) > 2) ? substr($payload, 2) : '';
    return array($code, $reason);
}
protected function closeCodeBytesToDec($bytes)
{
    return hexdec( dechex( ord($bytes[0]) ) . dechex( ord($bytes[1]) ) );
}
protected function closeCodeDecToBytes($dec)
{
    $hex = dechex($dec);
    $second = substr($hex, -2);
    $first = sprintf('%02s', substr($hex, 0, strlen($hex)-strlen($second)));
    return chr('0x' . $first) . chr('0x' . $second);
}
```

*suggestions welcome!*

Answer (score 1):

```
$payload = "\X03\Xe9Shutdown";
```

You need to set the status in a numerical context, not a string context.

The easiest way to inject binary data into a string is to add it as an escaped hexadecimal number.

My calculator tells me that hex 03e9 == dec 1001, but you can confirm this yourself: 3*256 + 14*16 + 9 = 1001.

If you had left it as it was, your first two bytes would be the ascii characters "10", which in a numerical context is 12592. (49*256 + 48)

```
$ php -a
php > $test ="\X03\Xe9Shutdown";
php > var_dump($test);
string(10) "?Shutdown"
php > var_dump(ord($test[0]));
int(3)
php > var_dump(ord($test[1]));
int(233)
```

It can also be done with the PHP `pack()` function, if you find escaped hex in your strings to be ugly:

```
$ php -a
php > $test = pack('n*', 1001) . 'Shutdown';
php > var_dump($test);
string(10) "?Shutdown"
php > var_dump(ord($test[0]));
int(3)
php > var_dump(ord($test[1]));
int(233)
```

Comment: `$payload = "\X03\Xe9Shutdown";` didnt worked for me. but `ord(0x03) . ord(0xe9) . 'shutdown'` works. thanks a lot! was looking into this since weeks :D